# Valid date check with DateTime.TryParse method

Tags: c#, datetime, tryparse

I am using `Datetime.TryParse` method to check the valid datetime. the input date string would be any string data. but is returning false as the specify date in invalid.

```
DateTime fromDateValue;
if (DateTime.TryParse("15/07/2012", out fromDateValue))
{
    //do for valid date
}
else
{
    //do for in-valid date
}
```

**Edit:** I missed. I need to check the valid date with time as "15/07/2012 12:00:00".

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: This is always a dangerous thing... parsing depends on the culture of the user. Always try to keep it in mind? "15/07/2012" is valid in France while it is not in USA...

Comment: if you are using a locale which expects a MM/DD/YYYY format, then 15/07/2012 is an invalid date.

Comment: @Jason you are right, my locale is MM/dd/yyyy formate. and so, it's invalid.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You could use the [TryParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h9b85w22) method which allows you to pass a collection of possible formats that you want to support. The `TryParse` method is culture dependent so be very careful if you decide to use it.

So for example:

```
DateTime fromDateValue;
string s = "15/07/2012";
var formats = new[] { "dd/MM/yyyy", "yyyy-MM-dd" };
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(s, formats, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out fromDateValue))
{
    // do for valid date
}
else
{
    // do for invalid date
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should be using `TryParseExact` as you seem to have the format fixed in your case.

Something like can also work for you

```
DateTime.ParseExact([yourdatehere],
                    new[] { "dd/MM/yyyy", "dd/M/yyyy" },
                    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                    DateTimeStyles.None);
```

Answer (score 0):

As the others said, you can use `TryParseExact`.

For more informations and the use with the time, you can check the [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/ms131044.aspx)