# Regular Expression for Date Format(MM/dd)

Tags: asp.net, regex

I have a textbox which needs to accept the date in the format MM/dd, can someone suggest me the regular Expression for doing that

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Better you should use Mask extender for that.

Comment: It is not possible to get a correct reqex without the year (29 of feb). You should use DateTime.TryParse to do this correct.

Comment: And a regex won't help if `September 1752` was in question.

Comment: @peer, Can you please elaborate with a bit of code for that

Comment: @SudhakarByna take a look at this post that explains how to use Datetime.TryParse to validate datetime inputs. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11310439/valid-date-check-with-datetime-tryparse-method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To validate the day of the month is correct would be easier with some programming logic. To answer the question on how to validate the the user entered a xx/xx where xx's are 1 or 2 digit numbers

In powershell I'd use something like

```
$String = "02/24"

if ($String -match "(\d{1,2})/(\d{1,2})") {
    # some code they got it right
    Write-Host "good job"
    # display the matches
    $matches
    } # end if

 # blank line
write-host 
    $months = $(@(1..12) + @(1..9 | %{ $_.ToString("00") } ) ) -join "|"
    $days = $(@(1..31) + @(1..9 | %{ $_.ToString("00") } ) ) -join "|"
    write-host "months: " $months
    write-host "days: " $days

if ($String -match "^($months)/($days)$") {
    # some code they got it right
    Write-Host "Slightly more complex good job"
    # display the matches
    $matches
    } # end if
```

yields

```
good job

Name                           Value                                                                                                                                
----                           -----                                                                                                                                
2                              24                                                                                                                                   
1                              02                                                                                                                                   
0                              02/24                                                                                                                                

months:  1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|11|12|01|02|03|04|05|06|07|08|09
days:  1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|11|12|13|14|15|16|17|18|19|20|21|22|23|24|25|26|27|28|29|30|31|01|02|03|04|05|06|07|08|09
More complex good job
2                              24                                                                                                                                   
1                              02                                                                                                                                   
0                              02/24
```

The first if block is quick and dirty, validating you provided at least 2 digits for each field. The second if block does a little better validation and only allows values which could be used as dates.