# DateTime.TryParseExact fails

Tags: c#

I need a method that converts a string to a datetime.
The format for the datetime must be `dd/MM/yyyy`
If the string is in any other format, the method will return null.

This is wat I have so far :

```
    private DateTime? StringToDateTime(string value)
    {
        DateTime? Result = null;
        DateTime test = DateTime.Now.Date;
        if (DateTime.TryParseExact(value, "dd/MM/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InstalledUICulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out test))
            Result = test;
        return Result;
    }
```

and to test it I use this

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string value = "01/01/2015";
        DateTime? test = StringToDateTime(value);
        if (test == null)
            MessageBox.Show("invalid date entered");
        else
            MessageBox.Show(test.ToString()); 
    }
```

Now the problem is that the `TryParseExact` always fails.
I also tried `"dd/mm/yyyy"` as format, but with same results.

So I must be doing something wrong here.
Does anybody has an example how to use `DateTime.TryParseExact` or is there another way of doing this ?

EDIT: This is not a duplicate since the "duplicate" link advises to use TryParseExact while my question is using this from the start and is asking why it does not work

Comment: possible duplicate of [valid date check with DateTime.TryParse method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11310439/valid-date-check-with-datetime-tryparse-method)

Comment: Works for me. Can you post a short but complete program that exhibits the error?

Comment: What is `value` exactly? Can you please debug your code and tell us? And what is your `InstalledUICulture`? It is impossible to help you without these information.

Comment: you are looking at the complete program. Its a winform with a button on it. Thats it, only code is the onclick you see here

Comment: @Liam: that doesn't look like a duplicate to me. The one you linked seems to be answered with "use TryParseExact" whereas this one is using that from the start and asking why it doesn't work. Is that definitely the question you meant or did you misread something maybe?

Comment: If you want a reproducible outcome without surprises then *don't* use CultureInfo.InstalledUICulture.  Use InvariantCulture instead.

Comment: @Soner I do not understand your question. The code you see here is the complete code from my test project, value is a string. Its all there

Comment: `CultureInfo.InstalledUICulture` has to be the culprit. It will probably be something else than you expect. You should just use `CurrentCulture` or even `InvariantCulture` if you want more reliability.

Comment: Ah, on my screen it cut off at "Cultureinfo.In" and I just assumed it was invariant culture. :) That'll teach me to not read things properly. :)

Comment: @Chris The answer is the same. If the OP does what the accepted answer in that question says, it will solve this issue.

Comment: not exactly, I can use the accepted answer in that question to figure out why my TryParseExact did not work, that is true, But it is still an answer to a different question. Anyway, I solved my problem so no use in debating this now

Comment: @Liam: You are right but the answer being the same does not mean the question is the same...

Comment: @Liam Answer is not the same. In the "duplicate" link the answer is : use TryParseExact and here the answer is : your TryParseExact did not work because you used wrong parameter. So, question is different and answer is different

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your code to:

```
DateTime? Result = null;
DateTime test = DateTime.Now.Date;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(value, "dd/MM/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out test))
    Result = test;
```

The change is to use **CultureInfo.InvariantCulture** instead of **CultureInfo.InstalledUICulture**.

Answer (score 1):

For me the format was an issue, with the following code it accepts 01/01/2015 as well as 1/1/2015 (`dd/MM/yyyy` and `d/M/yyyy`):

```
DateTime? Result = null;
DateTime test = DateTime.Now.Date;
var formats = new[] { "dd/MM/yyyy", "d/M/yyyy" };
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(value, formats , System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out test))
    Result = test;
```

Comment: I had not thought about that, good catch